# Robust Visual HTML Editor to JavaScript app

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, wysiwyg, visual-editor

I'm searching for robust HTML Visual Editor solution, which is implementable to Meteor javascript project. Paid or free/open-source, it's not depend, but 'easy' implementable, stable, safe, splitted to desing modules, etc.

I'm searching for Visual Editor, something like Elementor https://elementor.com/,
(not only simple WYSIWYG editor like CKEditor, TinyMCE or etc) but implementable to own meteor app.

...especially, I prefer, If you have own developer/designer positive experience with concrete Visual Editor solution implemented to own JavaScript app.

...and ideally, if editor is available on npm.

Thanks a lot for each answer, idea or experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at codemirror, or ace, both of which will give you the ability to edit js with syntax highlighting, If you want to have advanced IDE capability (as you seem to want), then it's a whole bunch more work.

This is an example of simple code editor (for Markdown files) https://example-ide.meteorfarm.com/

Petar Karpaonic has done some good work with Meteor Kitchen, you might look around at his site for some inspiration.

Comment: Hi @Mikkel, I§m searching for something else you know. I'm searching for Visual Editor something like Elementor, Divi https://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/ ...or something similar, which is possible to implement into Meteor app. Thx a lot.

Comment: I'm searching something like this: https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/